# Check if field is set in procedure: SQLAnywhere

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere

is there a way to check, if a field in a table is set by a procedure in Sybase Anywhere v12?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Sybase Central as DBA or as the procedure owner you can SQL for the procedure.

From the [documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbusage/alteringprocedures.html):

1. Use the SQL Anywhere 12 plug-in to connect to the database as a user with DBA or Resource authority.
2. In the left pane, double-click Procedures & Functions.
3. Select the procedure.
4. Use one of the following methods to edit the procedure:

   - In the right pane, click the SQL tab.
   - Right-click the procedure and click Edit In New Window.